# event.target.value is undefined for buttons that wrap an image instead of text

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have two buttons that are identical, except one has an image inside it and the other has text. I have added an onClick event handler to both.

The event.target.value for the image button is undefined, despite having a value and the text button has the correct value.

See this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/84885/

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.changeSlide = this.changeSlide.bind(this);
  }

  changeSlide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('e.target.value', e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button
        onClick={this.changeSlide}
        value="back">
        <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/7150a453468d14f599772cd8330fcf25/?default=&s=80" alt="Previous slide" />
      </button>

        <button
          onClick={this.changeSlide}
          value="back">
          CLICK ME
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Why is this the case and what is the correct way to use images inside buttons?

Comment: so if you change your fiddle to show you e.target, you'll notice that e.target is the button for the text, but it's actually the image for the image, and the images .value is not "back", it's undefined.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to change `target` to `currentTarget`:

```
changeSlide(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
}
```

From the DOM Event documentation:

> Event.currentTarget Identifies the current target for the event, as
>   the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which
>   the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which
>   identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: Please accept the answer as correct if it fixes your problem :)

Comment: This worked! I had similar issue with **Material UI MenuItem** having `onClick` function which setState to `e.target.value` but it wouldn't work in MenuItem had image inside. Basicly that image wasn't clickable as `e.target.value` would return _undefined_ every time. Using `e.currentTarget.value` instead worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

For some DOM elements, you should use `textContent` rather than `value` which works more for input elements

```
changeSlide(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent)
}
```

Checkout [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012375/11737951) for more.