# Why am i getting a NaN error in my react app?

Tags: reactjs

Been looking through this for a while. cant understand why i am getting the error. this is in a react app, with a wave form, the play skip forwards and backwards buttons all work but clicking on the notes doesn't, they're meant to skip to the corresponding time stamp when click. when i click on a note at the moment it says that i get a NaN error in the console. the error seems to be stemming from the bottom div. any help would be much appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Wavesurfer from "react-wavesurfer";
import audio from "./PM1.mp3";

require("wavesurfer.js");

export default class Waveform extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      pos: 0
    };
    this.handleTogglePlay = this.handleTogglePlay.bind(this);
    this.handlePosChange = this.handlePosChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTogglePlay() {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
  }
  handlePosChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      pos: e.originalArgs ? e.originalArgs[0] : +e.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    const waveOptions = {
      progressColor: "darkorange",
      waveColor: "orange"
    };
    let notes = this.props.notes;
    return (
      <div>
        <Wavesurfer
          audioFile={audio}
          pos={this.state.pos}
          onPosChange={this.handlePosChange}
          playing={this.state.playing}
          options={waveOptions}
        />

        <button
          value={this.state.pos - 5}
          onClick={value => this.handlePosChange(value)}
        >
          SkipBack
        </button>

        <button onClick={this.handleTogglePlay}>PLAY</button>

        <button
          value={this.state.pos + 5}
          onClick={value => this.handlePosChange(value)}
        >
          SkipForward
        </button>

        <h4>{this.props.pos}</h4>
        <div className="form-group col-xs-4">
          <label htmlFor="simple-pos">Position:</label>
          <input
            name="simple-pos"
            type="number"
            step="0.01"
            value={this.state.pos}
            onChange={this.handlePosChange}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <header className="App-header">Notes</header>
          {notes.map(notes => (
            <button
              className="yay2"
              value={this.state.pos + notes.time}
              onClick={value => this.handlePosChange(value)}
            >
              <h3>
                Time : {notes.timecode} - Description : {notes.description}
              </h3>
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the notes are formatted like so:

```
  notes:[
    {
      timecode: "1:00",
      time: 60,
      description: "Note 1"
    },
    {
      timecode: "2:00",
      time: 120,
      description: "Note 2"
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<button>` is a HTML element, it doesn't know anything about `react-wavesurfer` and when you click on it, the events are DOM events and have `originalArgs` information.

Also, `button` has no `value` passed on the `event.target` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882908/669586 for an explanation).

What happens when we click the following button:

```
<button
   className="yay2"
   value={this.state.pos + notes.time}
   onClick={event => this.handlePosChange(event)}
>
```

is that an `event` is passed to `handlePosChange` handler:

```
pos: e.originalArgs ? e.originalArgs[0] : +e.target.value
```

Since the event has no `originalArgs`, `+e.target.value` is executed. However, the `value` is `undefined`, therefore the following happens:

```
pos: +undefined
```

and `+undefined` is `NaN`.

To fix it:

1. change how `handlePosChange` works:

   ```
   handlePosChange(newPos) {
     this.setState({
       pos: newPos
     });
   }
   ```
2. update your elements:

   ```
   <Wavesurfer
      ...
      onPosChange={event => this.handlePosChange(event.originalArgs[0])}
   />

   <input
     ...
     value={this.state.pos}
     onChange={event => this.handlePosChange(+event.target.value)}
   />

   <button
     ...
     onClick={() => this.handlePosChange(this.state.pos + notes.time)}
   >
   ```