# Give the difference between input.value and input.textContent. Why is one used instead of the other?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why is it that `input.value` is used instead of `input.textContent`.  What is the difference between both?

For example, if I want to retrieve content from an input box

```
<input type="number">
```

I have to use this code

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");

input.value
```

instead of this one

```
input.textContent
```

Just want to get a clearer understanding of each.

Comment: `input.value` is for form elements to get the value of the form element. `input.textContent` is for other elements to get the content of the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript 'value' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217872/javascript-value-property)

Comment: @codeherk How is it a duplicate, the link you added asks 'If "Value" is only used for manipulating text content of input type controls', while I'm asking for a clearer understanding of the difference between value and textContent.

Comment: `textContent` essentially gets all Text children of the node. Every Element node has this property. Think of it as litterally getting the text between the the opening and closing tags (i.e. `<span>this text</span>`). But it only works for elements that have children. An input element node doesn't have children.

Comment: @codeherk I looked at it. It still does not clearly answer the question of explaining the difference between value and textContent as it pertains to input.

Comment: Well, if you think about the HTML, it makes sense: `<input type="text" value="something">`. There's no text between the start and end tags (since there's no end tag [technically there's no start tag either]), so no `textContent`, but there is a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> [...] `textContent` returns the concatenation of the `textContent` of every child node, excluding comments and processing instructions. This is an empty string if the node has no children.

Essentially, `textContent` gives you a textual representation of what a node *contains*. Think of it as being everything between the opening and closing tags, e.g.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('span').textContent);
```

```html
<span> this text </span> but not this one
```

`<input>` elements however [cannot have children](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) [(content model: nothing)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing). The value that is associated with them can only be accessed via the `value` property.

Answer (score 3):

Only **input elements** have a "value". It represent the input data supplied by the user or provided initially by the code. Whereas **textContent** property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

**textContent** returns the concatenation of the textContent of every child node, excluding comments and processing instructions and if  if the node has no children then textContent  will be empty string.

Comment: Please cite your [sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).