# puppeteer check value input after type

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer, pptr-testing-library and I'm trying to open google website and type in search input "tutorials" and after that I want to check that the value in the input is the same as I type "tutorials" but I get an error

```
 Unable to find an element with the text: tutorials".
```

[image]

The code:

```
import { PuppeteerScreenRecorder } from "puppeteer-screen-recorder";
import puppeteer, { Browser, ElementHandle, Page } from "puppeteer";
import { getDocument, queries } from "pptr-testing-library";
const { findByRole } = queries;
let page, recorder, browser;
beforeAll(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  page = await browser.newPage();
  recorder = new PuppeteerScreenRecorder(page);
  await recorder.start(`./screenshots/e2e-test-${Date.now()}.mp4`);
  await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
  console.log({ page });
});

describe("type in search input", () => {
  it("should check search input value", async () => {
    console.log("enter test");
    const $document = await getDocument(page);
    console.log("doc is", $document);
    const $searchInput = await findByRole($document, "combobox");
    await $searchInput.type("tutorials");
    console.log({ $searchInput });
    expect(await queries.findAllByText($document, 'tutorials"')).toBeTruthy();
    await recorder.stop();
    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

In addition when I print the logs of doc and searchInput I get empty object:

[image]

How to get the value of the input after typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Root cause

There is a typographical error in the following line of code:

```
expect(await queries.findAllByText($document, 'tutorials"')).toBeTruthy();
```

Please, note the «redundant» double quotation mark: `'tutorials"'`.

Please, note that the error message also contains the «redundant» double quotation mark:

> Evaluation failed: Error: Unable to find an element with the text: tutorials". This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

## Solution

Correct the line by removing the «redundant» double quotation mark:

```
expect(await queries.findAllByText($document, 'tutorials')).toBeTruthy();
```

It would be better to extract and reuse the constant. For example:

```
<…>
const searchInputString = 'tutorials';
await $searchInput.type(searchInputString);
<…>
expect(await queries.findAllByText($document, searchInputString)).toBeTruthy();
<…>
```

## Answers to questions

### Question #1

> How to get the value of the input after typing?

> how can I get the value from searchInput?

The [`Page.evaluate()` method](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v17.1.3/docs/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate.md) may be used to get property values of an element.

For example, to get the value of the `value` property of the input element:

```
const expectedSearchInputValue = 'tutorials';
await $searchInput.type(expectedSearchInputValue);

const searchInputValue = await page.evaluate(element => element.value, $searchInput);
console.log("Search input value:", searchInputValue);
expect(searchInputValue).toEqual(expectedSearchInputValue);
```

Please, note the argument of the `Page.evaluate()` method call — the arrow function.

- The `element` parameter of the arrow function is an instance of the [`HTMLInputElement` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) because the element handle corresponds to the input element.

#### Additional references

- Tests, which may serve as examples. [pptr-testing-library/extend.test.ts at v0.7.0 · testing-library/pptr-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/pptr-testing-library/blob/v0.7.0/test/extend.test.ts)
- Tests, which may serve as examples. [puppeteer/evaluation.spec.ts at v17.1.3 · puppeteer/puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v17.1.3/test/src/evaluation.spec.ts).
- Additional related method. [`Page.evaluateHandle()` method](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v17.1.3/docs/api/puppeteer.page.evaluatehandle.md).

### Question #2

> and why the searchInput in empty object?

Because:

- The `$searchInput` variable contains an instance of the [`ElementHandle` class](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v17.1.3/docs/api/puppeteer.elementhandle.md).
- Basically, it is just a handle, not the element itself.

Comment: sergey, that's right.. in addition, regarding to the questions, how can I get the value from searchInput? and why the searchInput in empty object?

Comment: Dear @Manspof, Please, see the updated answer. Please, note the «Answers to questions» section.

Comment: great.. thanks.. can you see my other question related to puppeteer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73803974/puppeteer-iframe-waitfornavigation-return-timeout

Answer (score 0):

```
**Hope it helps,
Just set the value of input like this:(Example**

await page.$eval('#email', el => el.value = 'test@example.com');

**Here is an example of using it on Wikipedia:**

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    await page.waitFor('input[name=search]');

    // await page.type('input[name=search]', 'Adenosine triphosphate');
    await page.$eval('input[name=search]', el => el.value = 'Adenosine triphosphate');

    await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitForSelector('#mw-content-text');
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const anchor = document.querySelector('#mw-content-text');
        return anchor.textContent;
    });
    console.log(text);
    await browser.close();
})();

Thank You!!
```

Comment: Hi Pr_veen! 
When working with Input element the only important part is the "value" property. Only input element is holding such propert. Working with textContent/innerText/innerHTML its quite risky.
Additionally there is big difference between innerText and textContent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

About value vs innerText, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179925/10413416 this answer, summarize very good the difference.

So i would change the anchor.textContent, to getting the input element value by it property.